# jQuery use multiple condition in if statement

Tags: jquery

i have 3 input fields like this

```
<input type="text" id="from-price" name="from-price"/>
<input type="text" id="to-price" name="to-price"/>
<input type="text" id="price" name="price"/>
```

and I want that when the values entered in all the fields it will show a button
So for that I have my code like this

```
var val1 = jQuery('#from-price').val().length;
        var val2 = jQuery('#to-price').val().length;
        var val3 = jQuery('#price').val().length;
if (val1 && val2 && val3  < 1 ) {
                jQuery('#add-fields').attr("disabled", false);
            }
```

But this is not working.

**Update**
Every time I am getting length 0 why? Even after text entered?

Comment: You might want to listen to an event and run that code every time that event occurs.

Comment: Use `console.log(jQuery('#from-price').val().length)` in firefox / chrome to see what values they output

Answer (score 5):

```
var elems = $('#from-price, #to-price, #price');

elems.on('keyup', function() {
    var hasValue = elems.filter(function() {
        return this.value.length
    }).length != elems.length;

    $('#add-fields').prop("disabled", hasValue);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/sGcMT/1/)

Answer (score 3):

```
var $i = $('input.prices').on('change', function(){
    var b = $i.filter(function() {
       return $.trim(this.value).length > 0; 
   }).length !== $i.length;

   $('#add-fields').prop("disabled", b);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace your if condition with the following:

```
if (val1 > 0 && val2 > 0 && val3 > 0 ) {
    jQuery('#add-fields').attr("disabled", false);
}
```

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Jwf8j/)

Comment: I suspect he wants to check if `val > 0` or similar instead, since he wants to enable only if all fields have something filled in.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson OP's if condition is contain the syntax error that's the main issue.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: "@Dh.." seems to be correct in his interpretation

Comment: @abhitalks "I want that when the values entered in all the fields it will show a button"

Comment: @Dh...every time I am getting length 0 why?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson i have update my you can check my jsfiddle demo too.

Comment: @NewUser please take a look into the jsfiddle demo. you can get the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use .prop() to set the disabled state

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    var $from = $('#from-price'),
        $to = $('#to-price'),
        $price = $('#price'),
        $add = $('#add-fields');

    $from.add($to).add($price).change(function () {
        $add.prop('disabled', !($.trim($from.val()).length && $.trim($to.val()).length && $.trim($price.val()).length))
    });
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/M3BuK/)

Comment: If you could only minify the code - it would make a beginner developer's life much easier...

Comment: You know: `jQuery(function(e){var t=e("#from-price"),n=e("#to-price"),r=e("#price"),i=e("#add-fields");t.add(n).add(r).change(function(){i.prop("disabled",!(e.trim(t.val()).length&&e.trim(n.val()).length&&e.trim(r.val()).length))})})`

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're checking the values only on page load. That's why it always shows 0 unless you prefill the form some way.

To make the check dynamic, put your code into a function and wrap it inside a [change](http://api.jquery.com/change/) function:

```
$('input').change(my_function);
```

Of course, it would be great to add a class to those three inputs you have and then use a class selector (in case there are more inputs on the page): `$('input.my_class')...`

Also, your if clause can be something like this:

```
if (val1 > 0 && val2 > 0 && val3 > 0) {
    jQuery('#add-fields').attr("disabled", false);
}
else {
    jQuery('#add-fields').attr("disabled", true);
}
```

Comment: Op is asking about multiple conditions in if statement. The event and handler he probably has already figured out.

Comment: @abhitalks I'm not sure about that: "I want that when the values entered in all the fields it will show a button"

Comment: That is where he is explaining his use-case. Please see the question title for the problem he is facing.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var val1 = jQuery('#from-price').val().length;
    var val2 = jQuery('#to-price').val().length;
    var val3 = jQuery('#price').val().length;

    if (val1 > 0 && val2 > 0 && val3  > 0 ) {
            jQuery('#add-fields').attr("disabled", "false");
    }
```

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you want to enable the button if all the fields are filled, if so then your `if` condition is incorrect. It should be greater then `0` which indicates that the field is not empty.Try this:

```
if (val1 > 0 && val2 > 0 && val3 > 0 ) {
     jQuery('#add-fields').attr("disabled", false);
     }
```

**Updated answer:**If you want to check instantly, then you need to attach an event handler.Try this:

```
$("input").on("keyup",function(){
    var val1 = jQuery('#from-price').val().length;
    var val2 = jQuery('#to-price').val().length;
    var val3 = jQuery('#price').val().length;
if (val1 >0 && val2 > 0 && val3  > 0 ) {
            jQuery('#add-fields').attr("disabled", false);
}
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/nsqXX/)

Comment: @NewUser Because you need a listener in order to check the values on every change and not only on the page load.

Comment: @Joke_Sense10 it is fine when I am entering values for the first time but when I am removing the values by backspace then it should again disable the button but in your fiddle when I am removing the values still its showing the button in active?

Answer (score 0):

I have put up a fix for this problem as part of this fiddle. Do let me know if that works for you.

http://jsfiddle.net/3STqm/

As part of the fiddle, the HTML code looks like:

```
<input type="text" id="from-price" name="from-price"/>
<input type="text" id="to-price" name="to-price"/>
<input type="text" id="price" name="price"/>
<button id="theButton">Submit</button>
```

And the jQuery code looks like:

```
var items = $("#from-price,#to-price,#price");

var button = $("#theButton").hide();

items.change(function(){
    var availableDataSize http://jsfiddle.net/3STqm/= items.map(function(){
        return $.trim($(this).val()) != "" ? true : null;
    }).length;                    
    availableDataSize == items.length ? button.show() : button.hide();
});
```

It simply tries to find the amount of data available and if that is equal to the number of fields, then show the button else hide it.

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).on('change','#from-price, #to-price, #price',function(){
    var val1 = jQuery('#from-price').val();
    var val2 = jQuery('#to-price').val();
    var val3 = jQuery('#price').val();
       if (val1!="" && val2!="" && val3!="" ) {
            jQuery('#add-fields').attr("disabled", false);
        }else{
            jQuery('#add-fields').attr("disabled", true); 
         }

});
```